# mess word when used scrapy to save json data to csv

Tags: python, json, csv

I used scrapy to crawl comment data from the website `http://club.jd.com/comment/productPageComments.action?callback=&productId=1892018&score=0&sortType=5&page=0&pageSize=10&isShadowSku=0`, which language is chinese. But i just got the output like this.[image]

And the csv file's output is all messed up.[image]

I don't know what happened. First i thought that was a `json decode` or `json encode` problem, then i tried the ways on the internet but i got the same result. Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8

import scrapy
from scrapy import Request
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from jd_comment.items import JdCommentItem
import json

class JdSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'comment'

    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'http://club.jd.com/comment/productPageComments.action?callback=&productId=1892018&score=0&sortType=5&page=0&pageSize=10&isShadowSku=0'
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        jsonresponse = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
        items = []
        for comment in jsonresponse['comments']:
            item = JdCommentItem()
            item['username'] = comment['nickname']
            item['user_ID'] = comment['id']
            item['time'] = comment['referenceTime']
            item['good_ID'] = comment['referenceId']
            item['good_name'] = comment['referenceName']
            item['content'] = comment['content']
            item['score'] = comment['score']

            items.append(item)

            yield item
```

Anyone give me a hint would be highly appreciated. Thanks.